# Issues with strtok()

Tags: c, arrays, token, strtok, execv

I'm attempting to split the string in "tmp" and put it into the array of pointers "arr". I'm doing this because I intend to used "execv" on "arr" but I can't because "arr" does not have NULL at the end. Instead it has "(null)" and when I print it's contents I get a segmentation fault. 
 How would I set "arr" correctly so that it can be used with execv? Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

    char tmp[40] = "echo Hello World \n ";
    char *arr[40];

    char *token = strtok(tmp, " \n");
    int index = 0;

    while(token != NULL){
        arr[index] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
        arr[index] = token;

        index = index + 1;
        token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        printf("%s \n", arr[i], arr[i]);
    }


    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a big problem:

```
arr[index] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
arr[index] = token;
```

You don't copy the string, instead you overwrite the pointer. You should use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to copy the string:

```
strcpy(arr[index], token);
```

In this case it might not be needed to copy the strings though, just the assignment will do. That also means no allocation are needed.

---

There's also another problem with your code: The loop where you print the strings in `arr`.

With the string you have you should only have three elements valid in `arr`, the rest will be uninitialized and *indeterminate*. Dereferencing them (like you do when you attempt to print the "strings" they point to) will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

After the previous loop, where you initialize `arr`, then `index` will be the number of valid elements in `arr`. Use that as the end of the printing-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){ ... }
```